# Selenium Python giving TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am having an issue with the code, it returns

TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

```
email = driver.find_element(By.ID("email-input")).getAttribute("id")
```

I read through some other threads and tried

```
email = driver.find_element(By.ID("email-input")).text
```

But it's not working

ERROR

> Traceback (most recent call last): File "C:\Users\user\Desktop\LAB AUTOMATION\LAB.py", line 42, in  email = driver.find_element(By.ID, "email-input").getAttribute("id") File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 855, in find_element return self.execute(Command.FIND_ELEMENT, { File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 428, in execute self.error_handler.check_response(response)

Comment: Can you show the full [traceback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61335714/what-is-traceback-in-python) error?

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\Desktop\LAB AUTOMATION\LAB.py", line 42, in <module>
    email = driver.find_element(By.ID, "email-input").getAttribute("id")
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 855, in find_element
    return self.execute(Command.FIND_ELEMENT, {
  File "C:\Users\\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 428, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)

Comment: File "C:\Users\Syed\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 243, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"[id="email-input"]"}
  (Session info: chrome=105.0.5195.127)
Stacktrace:
Backtrace:
 Ordinal0 [0x00FDDF13+2219795]
 Ordinal0 [0x00F72841+1779777]
 Ordinal0 [0x00E8423D+803389]
 Ordinal0 [0x00EB3025+995365]
 Ordinal0 [0x00EB31EB+995819]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please show a [complete](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359146) error message by the following steps: 1. [edit] the question. 2. **copy and paste**, starting from the line that says `Traceback (most recent call last):` **until the end, including** the line that says `TypeError`, into the post. 3. Put three backticks, **on a separate line**, **above and below** the pasted error message. Do not use the comments to show an error message, and make sure the error is properly formatted in the post.

Answer (score 0):

`find_element` takes a type string plus additional parameters based on type. `By.ID` is just the string "id". You want to use 2 parameters. The first flags that you are finding by id, and the second is the id to be found.

```
email = driver.find_element(By.ID, "email-input").getAttribute("id")
```

See [Locating Elements](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html) for more details on locating elements.

Comment: I tried that too but got this error  :      selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"[id="email-input"]"}

Comment: @SyedAsadHaider - I don't have your data but the error suggests that you don't have an element with that id.

Comment: <input id="email-input" placeholder="Email" dir="ltr" type="email" class="undefined form-control" aria-invalid="false" value="">

Comment: Here is the element

Comment: That is a new problem, and demands a new question. Make sure to follow all the steps (read [ask], [mre], https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592 first in order to understand how to ask questions properly) before asking. Note well that Stack Overflow is **not a discussion forum**. Posts here are **not** for the purpose of getting the problem with your code fixed; they are for the purpose of building a searchable Q&A library, as described in the [tour].